# can't add images as assets in Asset Browser

Tags: asset-browser

In Blender 3.0 Alpha I was allowed to add images as assets if i were to right click them in the outliner and they would work just like they do in the file browser

[image]

[image]

but now it won't let me do that anymore, is there a way to set these as assets, or did they remove that feature?

Comment: You'll need to download 3.1 Beta and enable "Extended Asset Browser" in the experimental panel of the preferences for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [3.0 Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Asset_Browser) specifically state what the initial release of the Asset Browser supports:

- Objects
- Materials
- Poses
- Worlds

That's it. That is all that is currently supported in 3.0.  There were several features in the alpha that didn't make it into the release because they weren't though to be robust enough.  There's a roadmap for when various features will be added to the browser but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: ah well, thats unfortunate. but it sounds like these features will eventually make it in so thats good.

Comment: It was a weird choice to ship the asset browser when it was so incomplete, but I agree that they shouldn't have shipped bits that weren't ready.  They'd set expectations so high they just couldn't convince themselves into postponing it until it was more useful.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the "why won't asset browser do this?" club. Population... a *lot* of us. So, I have learned that many types of things do not actually save in the asset browser. No parented meshes - only single meshes, materials and HDRI's (so far, that is all I have verified).

In the case where you want to save an image, I recommend saving it via saving a *Material* (which will, of necessity, include a pointer to the image in the blend file). It's a workaround, but it *will* work. The material will be saved in the library and a pointer to that file will be inside the material (because it'll be plugged into a node).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: **Confirmed** "Mark as Asset" is available in `RMB` context menu directly from `Outliner` view in VSE.
[image]

Confirmed video clip (.mp4) can successfully be marked as asset and added to Asset Browser.
[image]

The 3.1 release has "Asset Indexing" selected by default and "Asset Debug Info" as an option in `Experimental` in place of ["Extended Asset Browser"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254929/cant-add-images-as-assets-in-asset-browser#comment434773_254929)
[image]

[Mary Fouts' correct answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254969/90622) also highlights progress made from 3.0 -> 3.1 including explicit [VSE: Support drag and drop for datablocks from Outliner and Asset Browser](https://developer.blender.org/rBb42494cf6b00) fixes.

I'm checking out [DocBadwrench's saving as Material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254933/90622) workaround for image and video assets as less-than-fully supported Asset Browser assets.